# How to add buttons to UIView at zoom in point?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiscrollview, pinchzoom

i want to add a button to `UIView` after zoom in to specified point, i have an `UIView` on `UIScrollview` , with the help of `UITapGestureRecognizer` i can able to tap the view and zoom in the view with `UIScrollviewDelegates`, but now the issue is how to add the buttons to the zoomed view.

its just like the showing pins to `MKMapView`.,

This is my code 
http://pastebin.com/3zjgbzA1
This is my `UIView`
[image]

I need to add button to this zoom level 
[image]

Comment: How did you make that UIView and UIButton?
Using storyboard or prgrammatically?

Comment: i am not using storyboard and made the UIView and UIButton Programatically

Answer (score 1):

for adding button on scroll view at touch position, you need to find touch point in respect of scroll view instead on self.view.

And for finding touch point, you can use below statement:

CGPoint touchPoint = [tapgesture locationInView:scroller];

Thanks

Comment: is there any way to add button to scrollview touchpoint position ?

Comment: yes, you can get touch point as above and add button on this position as [scrollview addsubview:button]; and set button frame to touch point.

Comment: thanks,adding the button to UIView is worked as per your suggestion !